# How to translate this SQL join statement into an Ecto query?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a SQL query returns the only the latest messages sent to a user by any other user (i.e., "only show me the most recent message sent to me by each message sender"). In pure SQL I can get this work as follows:

```
select messages.* from messages
join
(select max(inserted_at) maxtime,sender_id from messages group by sender_id) latest
on messages.inserted_at=latest.maxtime and messages.sender_id=latest.sender_id and messages.receiver_id=2;
```

Any ideas on how to translate a nested join statement like this to an idiomatic Ecto query?

Comment: Sure. I can make the SQL above work using a fragment, which sort of seems to defeat the point of Ecto here. Honestly, I'm just experimenting with Elixir/Ecto on a hobby project and after combing the Ecto documentation, left with the impression this isn't currently possible. Was hoping Stack Overflow could prove me wrong.

Comment: It would help us to advise you if you'd share what you've already tried in Ecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I discovered I was able to do this using pure Ecto syntax using a `subquery` in a join, like this:

```
user_id = 2

subquery = from(s in Message,
                select: %{ sender_id: s.sender_id, max_time: max(s.inserted_at) },
                where: s.receiver_id == ^user_id,
                group_by: s.sender_id
               )

query = from(m in Message,
             join: s in subquery(subquery), on: m.inserted_at == s.max_time and m.sender_id == s.sender_id,
             where: m.receiver_id == ^user_id
            )

Repo.all(query)
```

For those interested, this when you inspect the query to see what the SQL looks like, here's the output:

```
 > Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql(:all, Repo, query)
 {"SELECT m0.\"id\", m0.\"sender_id\", m0.\"receiver_id\", m0.\"body\", m0.\"received_at\", m0.\"inserted_at\" FROM \"messages\" AS m0 INNER JOIN (SELECT m0.\"sender_id\" AS \"sender_id\", max(m0.\"inserted_at\") AS \"max_time\" FROM \"messages\" AS m0 WHERE (m0.\"receiver_id\" = $1) GROUP BY m0.\"sender_id\") AS s1 ON (m0.\"inserted_at\" = s1.\"max_time\") AND (m0.\"sender_id\" = s1.\"sender_id\") WHERE (m0.\"receiver_id\" = $2)", [30064, 30064]}
```

Not exactly pretty SQL, but when I tried it [in a SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16a0a/4) it runs basically the same execution play with the same execution time!

Thanks to @radzserg [whose answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47980046/1692922) turned me on to the missing piece of subqueries. Strangely, that question is worded and structured *almost exactly the same* as mine, but got 3 upvotes a year ago versus my 4 downvotes. Hope that doesn't portend a change in the way the Elixir/Ecto community treats beginners trying to get a handle on things!